# Creating a polynomial with a linked list in C

Tags: c

so I am trying to create a polynomial with a linked list in C, so far I am doing good but I have a small problem, if I try to insert 5 with exp 2 per example and 6 with exp 2 it will print 5X2 + 6X2, and I want my output to be 11X2. Is there a way I can change my code to let this happen?(I'm not sure it is possible)

Here is my code:

```
struct listNode
{
int coefficient;
int exponent;
struct listNode * nextPtr;
};
typedef struct listNode Node;

void insertNode(int cof,int exp, Node **start)
{
Node * node = (Node *)malloc(sizeof(Node));
if (node != NULL)       
{
    node->coefficient = cof;
    node->exponent = exp;
    node->nextPtr = NULL;

    Node * previousNode = NULL, * currentNode = *start;

    while (currentNode != NULL && currentNode->exponent > exp)
    {
        previousNode = currentNode;
        currentNode = currentNode->nextPtr;
    }

    if (previousNode != NULL)
    {
        previousNode->nextPtr = node;
        node->nextPtr = currentNode;
    }
    else
    {
        node->nextPtr = currentNode;
        *start = node;
    }
}
else
    puts("No available memory! Node not inserted!");
}

void printPolynomial(char const *tag, struct Node *ptr)
{
Node * temp;
const char *pad = "";
temp = ptr;
printf("%s: ", tag);
while (temp != NULL)
{
    if(temp->exponent==0){
        printf("%s%d", pad, temp->coefficient);
    temp = temp->nextPtr;
    }
    else{
         printf("%s%dX%d", pad, temp->coefficient, temp->exponent);
    temp = temp->nextPtr;

    }
    pad = " + ";

}
putchar('\n');
}
int main()
{
Node *p1=NULL;
Node **p2=&p1;
insertNode(3,5,p2);
insertNode(5,5,p2);
insertNode(8,0,p2);
printPolynomial("p1",p1);

return 0;
}
```

Comment: If you find a `X2` node already there, just add the coefficient, instead of inserting a duplicate node?

Comment: Unrelated to your problem, but in `main` you can simply write `insertNode(..., ..., &p1);` instead of making use of `p2`; latter only adds confusion.

Comment: ... and you should get rid of `struct` here: `void printPolynomial(char const *tag, struct Node *ptr)` to eliminate some warnings. This would be correct: `void printPolynomial(char const *tag, Node *ptr)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The insert function is wrong. You only need to store `coefficient` and `exponent` during insert. Otherwise use standard method for adding the nodes.

```
void insertNode(int cof, int exp, Node **start)
{
    Node *node = malloc(sizeof(Node));
    if (node != NULL)
    {
        node->coefficient = cof;
        node->exponent = exp;
        node->nextPtr = NULL;

        if (*start != NULL)
        {
            Node *walk = *start;
            Node *tail = NULL;
            while (walk)
            {
                tail = walk;
                walk = walk->nextPtr;
            }
            tail->nextPtr = node;
        }
        else
        {
            *start = node;
        }
    }
    else
        puts("No available memory! Node not inserted!");
}
```

Output after this modification:

> p1: 3X5 + 5X5 + 8

Also you don't need the cast in `Node *node = (Node*)malloc(sizeof(Node));` unless this is c++ program, in which case you shouldn't use `malloc` anyway. In general avoid using cast when the compiler didn't ask for it and didn't complain.

Answer (score 0):

```
if (previousNode != NULL)
{
    if (previousNode->exponent == exp)
    {
        previousNode->coefficient += coef;
        // Keep in mind you have allocated memory for node that you do not need
    }
    else
    {
        previousNode->nextPtr = node;
        node->nextPtr = currentNode;
    }
}
```

Comment: Perhaps rather than just providing some code, you could explain your answer?